# How do I get a shorter Runtime?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

```
num<-18.7
guess<- -1

print("Can you guess the daily dose per 1000 inhabititants in the UK?")

while(guess !=num) {
    guess<-readline(prompt = "Enter integer:")
    if (guess== num)
        cat(num, "is correct")
    if (guess<num)
        cat("it is bigger")
    if (guess>num)
        cat("It is smaller")
}
```

It works when I play it through r script but when I knit it into markdown it doesn't get an error or anything but its been running for about 30 minutes and still hasn't finished. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: What would be the expected output after knitting? Your script expects user input, but rmarkdown tries to produce a static document. In the process the system is waiting for the required user input.

Comment: I was to have an markdown file where someone else can have a guess at the number and then it tells them if they r right or wrong

Comment: @AmeliaJones I'm afraid you suffer from an conceptual misunderstanding: R code is executed when the document is *knitted*, not when it's *viewed*.

Comment: If you need interactivity, you may want to consider building a shiny app rather than knitting a markdown document.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the R code in a R Markdown document is executed when it is knitted, not when it is viewed. When talking about interactivity for R, one usually thinks about [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/). For some cases it is also possible to combine Shiny directly with R Markdown, c.f. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-documents.html. A straight forward conversion of your script gives:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

# Can you guess the daily dose per 1000 inhabititants in the UK?

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
num <- 18.7
```


```{r guessing-game, echo=FALSE}
numericInput("guess", label = "Enter number:", value = 0)

renderText({
    if (input$guess == num)
        paste(num, "is correct")
    else if (input$guess<num)
        "it is bigger"
    else if (input$guess>num)
        "It is smaller"
})
```
````

Such a document can either be run locally or [deployed](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-deploy.html). BTW, `==` is not the best choice for comparing floating point numbers. It is better to use `isTRUE(all.equal())`:

```
> 0.3 == 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(all.equal(0.3, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1))
[1] TRUE
```